# AttributeError: module 'wikipedia' has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia

```
import wikipedia
print (wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))
```

In this code, I am getting this problem:

> AttributeError: module 'wikipedia' has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: Try reinstalling wikipedia library using pip/pip3

Answer (score 10):

Did you perhaps do one of these things?

- You named your Python file *wikipedia.py*
- You named the folder where you are running your codes *wikipedia*

If so, just rename it to something else other than *wikipedia*.

```sh
$ cat wikipedia.py
import wikipedia
print(wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))

$ python wikipedia.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wikipedia.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wikipedia
...
    print(wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))
AttributeError: module 'wikipedia' has no attribute 'summary'

$ mv wikipedia.py myfile.py
$ python myfile.py
Wikipedia ( (listen) wik-ih-PEE-dee-ə or  (listen) wik-ee-PEE-dee-ə) is a multilingual online encyclopedia created ...
```

Generally, you should not name your own files, folders, packages, the same as the built-in or 3rd-party packages you are importing. Because if you do, then Python will use that instead of the correct packages.

Answer (score 2):

Your file name is Wikipedia. Python will select that instead of checking for the package. Always save your files with unique names